# Ошибка конкатенации строк

Tags: python

Я новичок в питоне. Я написал игру морской бой, но в изменении массива происходит ошибка
Код:

```
import random

userField = ["~", "~", "~", "~", "~"]
compField = ["~", "~", "~", "~", "~"]

compShip = random.randint(1, 5)

print("Ваше поле")
print(userField)

userShip = int(input("Поставьте корабль "))

userField[userShip] = "♥"
print("Ваше поле")
print(userField)

compShot = 0
userShot = 0

while compShot != userShot or userShot != compShip:
    print("Поле компа" + "\n" + str(compField))
    userShot = input("Стреляй ")
    if userShot == compShip:
        print("Победа!!!")
        compField[userShot] = "X"
        print("Поле бота " + "\n" + str(compField))
        break
    else:
        print("Мимо!")
        compField[str(userShot)] = "*"
        print("Поле бота " + "\n" + str(compField))
    print("Выстрел бота")
    print("Мое поле " + "\n" + str(userField))
    compShot = random.randint(1, 5)
    while userField[compShot] == "*":
        compShot = random.randint(1, 5)
        if compShot == userShip:
            userField[compShot] = "X"
            print(str(userField))
            print("Ты проиграл!")
            break
        else:
            userField[compShot] = "*"
            print(str(compField))
            print("Бот промахнулся")
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/Projects/WorldWar.py", line 30, in <module>
compField[str(userShot)] = "*"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 2):

В ошибке же ответ: индексы списка должны быть целыми числами(integers) или слайсами(slice), но не строками(str)

В строке 30 у вас `compField[str(userShot)] = "*"`, а должно быть `compField[int(userShot)] = "*"`